# TabView has delay when changing visibility

Tags: ios, swiftui, tabview

I have a TabView and in a certain subview I want to hide the toolbar. This can be done with `.toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)`. The problem is when the toolbar becomes visible again: the toolbar takes a long time to show up again.

It is easily reproducible with the following code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationStack {
                NavigationLink("Tap Me") {
                    Text("Detail View")
                        .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                }
                .navigationTitle("Primary View")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The delay can be seen in the following GIF
[image: GIF of TabView having a delay before it becomes visible again]

It honestly seems to me like this native functionality is bugged. I tried the [SwiftUI Introspect package](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) but also got a delay here.

Is there any fix for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed a little bit your code, place NavigationStack upon TabBar, because you can specify navigation stack like main view. So it works fine, without delay.

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            TabView {
                    NavigationLink("Tap Me") {
                        Text("Detail View")
                            .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                    }
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Primary View")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how would you do this with multiple tabs?

Comment: @frankcrest did you try just add another view with linked second tab Item? So I mean what exactly problem you faced?

Comment: I actually figured it out, I used the same structure as yours but I also had different tabs so I had to put the navigation title for each different tab, I ended up creating a function that outputs a string and depending on the selected tab, programatically switch the navigation title

Comment: @usaman I guess you right. But wait, the question of this topic is not about hierarchy of views in navigation stack. I just helped this guy to fix his bug. If u want to talk about navigation stack lets go to another topic

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get similar functionality to what I believe you are looking for by using the `.tabItem` modifier on the each view in a `MainTabView`.

```swift
struct MainTabView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            TabView{
                ExploreView()
                    .tabItem { Label("Explore", systemImage: "magnifyingglass") }
                
                WishlistView()
                    .tabItem { Label("Wishlists", systemImage: "heart") }
                
                
                ProfileView()
                    .tabItem { Label("Profile", systemImage: "person") }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is asking about the problem with toolbar visibility. Does your answer address that issue?

Comment: Yes, @HangarRash, the toolbar is hidden inside of a view as a modifier to a ScrollView. Without the NavigationStack over the TabView as shown there is noticeable lag. My above implementation solves this while allowing for multiple tabs, as another commenter questioned.